# Stata : Change name of variables with values of another Variables

Tags: variables, label, stata

I have a dataset of variables looking like this:
[Screenshot of the Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wa6ve.png).

I would like, if it is possible, to label the other variables with the name of the country they are related to. For example, `ggdy1` is the gross debt/GDP ratio for country 1, here Austria, while `ggdy2` is the Gross Debt/GDP ratio for country 2, Belgium.

To avoid the back and forth from the dataset to the results or command windows, is there a way to label the different variables (`ggdy`, `pby`,...) automatically with the name of the suitable country?

I have 28 countries in my dataset and work on Stata 15.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you want your result to look like? I don't see how you want to label variables that contain data for multiple countries with the name of one country only.

Comment: @Wouter thank you for your comment. I would like variable ggdy1 be labeled with the value of variable country1, i.e. Austria, ggdy2 be labeled with the value of variable country2, Belgium, ...

Comment: What about the other 26 countries?

Comment: Screenshots are harder work for people answering than data examples. Please read the `stata` tag wiki for detailed advice.

Answer (score 0):

I have to say I think this is the wrong question. Your data structure is analogous to this

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input float year str7 country1 float(y1 x1) str7 country2 float(y2 x2)
1990 "Austria" 12 16 "Belgium" 20 24
1991 "Austria" 14 18 "Belgium" 22 26
end
```

which is both logical and perverse for most Stata purposes. A simple `reshape` gets you to a structure that is much more useful for most analyses.

```
. reshape long country y x , i(year) j(which)
(note: j = 1 2)

Data                               wide   ->   long
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Number of obs.                        2   ->       4
Number of variables                   7   ->       5
j variable (2 values)                     ->   which
xij variables:
                      country1 country2   ->   country
                                  y1 y2   ->   y
                                  x1 x2   ->   x
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

. l

     +----------------------------------+
     | year   which   country    y    x |
     |----------------------------------|
  1. | 1990       1   Austria   12   16 |
  2. | 1990       2   Belgium   20   24 |
  3. | 1991       1   Austria   14   18 |
  4. | 1991       2   Belgium   22   26 |
     +----------------------------------+
```

`which` does no harm, but is not essential.

P.S. What you ask for is programmable too, something like

```
foreach v of var ggdy* { 
    local suffix = substr("`v'", 5, .)
    local where = country`suffix'[1]  
    label var `v' "ggdy `where'" 
    label var pby`suffix' "pby `where'" 
    label var cby`suffix' "cby `where'" 
    label var fby`suffix' "fby `where'" 
}
```